# Monitor output is always my touchscreen, not my computer monitor

Tags: touchscreen, monitoring

So, I got a Raspberry 3 model B and connected it with a keyboard, a mouse, and a touchscreen. When I connect an HDMI-DVI converter to my Planar monitor, it's fine at the beginning of turning on the RPi. However, my computer monitor stopped loading after some time, like the picture showing here. 
[image]

Then, my touchscreen works and loads into the desktop, leaving my computer monitor like the picture shows.

I searched on the Internet and tried to modify the code in config.txt.
Uncomment the line hdmi_force_hotplug=1

Uncomment the line hdmi_group=2

Uncomment the line hdmi_mode=16

Uncomment the line hdmi_drive=1

But, it still doesn't work. I really don't know what I should do now.
I hope you can help me!

Comment: That is by design you get one or the other, I have seen some youtube videos claiming to run both but have not tried it myself.

Comment: Actually, I don't need 2 screens. I want to show things on my computer monitor. But even I take my touchscreen off, my computer screen still acts like the picture shows. I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the waveshare 3.5in. TFT (or a compatible display), You can switch back to HDMI mode with the following commands:

```
cd LCD-show/
./LCD-hdmi
```

Then remove the touchscreen and reboot your Pi.

More details can be found on the [waveshare wiki](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)).

If your screen came with a prebuilt SD card image or SD card, you will need to switch to the standard Raspbian image. To allow switching between your regular and touchscreen easier I would suggest burning the standard image to a new card. Full details on downloading and burning the image can be found on the Pi Foundation's [download page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

It appears you are running Occidentalis (an Adafruit modified version of Raspbian) therefore it is likely you are also using an Adafruit PiTFT (you could confirm this bt looking at the TFT's board, it should have the adafruit logo and name printed on it. The simplest method of switching back to your Planar monitor would be to download Raspbian as mentioned above, and burning a new SD card.

Comment: Thanks! I tried these commands in the Terminal, but it shows that "No such file or directory".

Comment: What touchscreen do you have? How did you install it? How did you configure it? What instructions did you follow? Did the screen come with an SD card? or did you burn your own? If you burnt it yourself what image did you burn (specifically - where did you get it)? what is the output of sudo find / -iname LCD-show?

Comment: I think the touchscreen is waveshare 3.5in. TFT. But I don't know other details because it was configured by others in our lab long ago. I found that if I take off the touchscreen, the program hangs on with "random: nonblocking pool is initialized".

Comment: And the output of sudo find / -iname LCD-show is nothing, leaving me to input another command.

Comment: I think I could open a new question because I don't need two screens. Now, the problem is: without a touchscreen, my computer monitor hangs on when turning on the power, like the picture shows.

Comment: Assuming it is a waveshare you could download the software from the wiki page I linked to and run the above commands. That should restore the functionality to the full size monitor.

Comment: Thanks! I enter the wiki page. I was wondering which software do I need to download? I saw Panasonic SDFormatter, Win32DiskImager and PuTTY. And I need to download the software and set up in my Rpi? In which folder?

Comment: @TianXie if you go to the waveshare wiki you can download this file LCD-show-170703.tar.gz  from that page expand the archive (tar xvzf LCD-show-170703.tar.gz). Then switch into the newly created directory and run the ./LCD-hdmi command.

Comment: @TianXie If you want to burn a new SD card go to the download page (link at the end of my answer above) and download the Rasbian Jessie with Desktop image and on the same page there is a link to the installation guide.

Comment: Holly Thanks!!! It works!!! My touchscreen is adafruit 3.5in. It's on Jessie Pi installs. Thanks!!